# Template not found for name and path in Grails 2.x

Tags: grails

I´m trying to render a template outside of my controllers scope.

The view where i want to render the template is located in views/home/index.gsp

**Edit:**

I try to render the templates "**_list-clients.gsp**" and "**_list-hubs.gsp**", both located in **/views/templates** in my main layout "**main.gsp**" located in **/views** by using a taglib that i invoke in a view "**list.gsp**" located in **/views/client**

Here´s how i include the content-tag to the view :

```
<g:pageProperty name="page.client-menu"/>
```

Here i invoke the taglib in a content-tag in the list.gsp:

```
<content tag="client-menu">
    <g:createClientMenu ></g:createClientMenu>
</content>
```

And here is my taglib:

```
package com.pmedia.taglib

import com.pmedia.domain.Company

class CreateClientMenuTagLib {

def createClientMenu = {        attrs, body ->
    def company = Company.findByName("pMediaNetwork")

    out << '<ul>'
    out << '<li class="dropdown">'
    out << '<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">'
    out << 'Select Hub or Client for ' + company?.name
    out << '<b class="caret"></b>'
    out << '</a>'
    out << '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">'
    if ( company?.getHubs()) {
        out << render(template:"/templates/list-hubs", collection: company.getHubs(), var:"hubs")
    }
    if ( company?.getClients()) {
        out << render(template:"/templates/list-clients", collection: company.getClients(), var:"clients")
    }
    out << '</ul>'
    out << '</li>'
    out << '</ul>'

    }
}
```

The template is located in views/templates/_list-hubs.gsp

I keep getting this error:

```
URI
/newLayout/home/index

Class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException

Message
Template not found for name [templates/list-hubs] and path [/home/templates/_list-hubs.gsp]
```

I expected grails to start looking in the view folder when i lead the URL with a "/" but for some reasons the template can´t be found.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: The code and the error don't seem to be related. Your rendering code uses the template `/templates/list-hubs` while your error message is for the template `templates/list-clients`. You have forgotten the leading slash for the **clients** template.

Comment: I´m sorry i didn´t reload the browser when posting the error. I edited it above for the actual error.

Comment: Still looks as if you're missing the leading slash. Also, are you calling `render` in a scriptlet block (`<% ...%>`)? This is [discouraged](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#GSPBasics). Why not use the `<g:render>` tag (or the [template namespace](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates))?

Comment: Just a note... You render in a view. Then why don't you render via tags, e.g. `<g:renger template="/templates/list-hubs" ... />`?

Comment: I tested it in 2.1.1 environment, if you put the `render` part in a controller it works fine. But it's better not to use `templates` to avoid confusion because it is reserved for scaffolding templates folder in `src` directory.

Comment: Again i updated the description for the error a bit because its not just rendering to a view but by using layouts and and taglibs. Sorry for adding that information just now

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the error. I called the templates recursively. And in one of my templates the path was not correct... Sorry for bothering for such a stupid mistake. Next time i post an error on stackoverflow i´ll make sure to post all of the involved code.
Thanks anyway to everyone who helped out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `/views` prefix from the lines `out << render(template:"...", ...)`.

Comment: i tried both, template:"/views/templates/..." and template:"/templates/..." and still getting the error.

Comment: Could you please review the edited question given above? I guess it was missing some information at first.

Comment: Try to localize the problem. What if you literally call the `<g:createClientMenu ></g:createClientMenu>` instead of the `<g:pageProperty name="page.client-menu"/>`? What if you inline the desired content directly in the `<content tag="client-menu">` instead of using the taglib? What if you apply both those simplifications simultaneously?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Tomorrow at work i´ll try some of your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is right, you need to put `/templates` to the `/grails-app/views`, instead of put it to `/grails-app/views/layout/views`.

I tested your code for quite a while but failed to got the error. Actually I removed

```
<g:pageProperty name="page.client-menu"/>
```

and

```
<content tag="client-menu">
```

and just keep

```
<g:createClientMenu ></g:createClientMenu>
```

, with which the code works fine.

When I carefully read your question post again, I noticed this:

> ... the templates "_list-clients.gsp" and
>   "_list-hubs.gsp", both **located in /views/templates in my main layout**
>   "main.gsp" located in /views ...

So I tried to put `_list-clients.gsp` to `/layout/views/templates`, the error is reproduced. That's why I guess you put the `template` folder to a path inconsistent with the taglib.